Can I remove all the caps in the game (from all NPCs, etc.) at a particular moment of the game using a console command?
Can I remove all the caps in the game (from all NPCs, etc.) at a particular moment of the game using a console command?
The goal is to turn Fallout: New Vegas into a barter economy as much as possible. It's okay that caps will "respawn" at some vendors later, and the quests will still reward caps.
